# How to split array by 3 php

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**
I have a form table with multiple textbox and one submit button

[image]

Im using implode but all value's are inserted in array

```
$val = implode(',',$textboxval);
```

result is (80,80,80,40,80,90,70,70,70)
What i want is i want to insert each row of data's in an group of array in the database
[0]=(80,80,80),[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKOsL.png)=(40,80,90),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEqTp.png)=(70,70,70)
**RESULT**
[image]

Comment: How do the text box values end up in `$textboxval`?

Comment: <input type='number' name='textboxval[]' multiple/>

Comment: I've done this sort of thing in the past with a prepared query, and generating a string full of question marks and the parenthesis based on the length you need. You'd have an empty array, then based on the length you need, append the string `"(?,?,?)"` to the array. Then implode the array on `","`.  You now have a string like `"(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)"` now toss in a `VALUES` in front so you have `"VALUES(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)"` then bind your array of values to the question marks.

Comment: can you provide some example code ? i only use mysqli query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
foreach (array_chunk($textboxval, 3) as $values) {
   $val = implode(',', $values);
   // insert $val into database
}
```

Comment: no luck, $val values is resulting to word Array in the database

Comment: Try my edited code. I forgot you were trying to write a string.